# Which are the MediaElement.js scripts to enqueue

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, video-player

I'm loading (paging) posts with ajax, so I want to be able to render videos using MediaElement.js on newly appended content.

I already have my script working but is failing if no video posts are included on the initial page.

I imagine that if I enqueue the appropriate scripts on the blog pages `is_home()`, `is_archive()`, `is_tag()` then it will work even if no posts with videos are on the initial page.

Currently I'm trying this already got rid of the js error `undefined mediaelement()`
but still videos are not rendering properly.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\pmt_mejs');
function pmt_mejs() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        if ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_tag() ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'mediaelement' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-mediaelement' );
        }
    }
}
```

Haven't found any resources out there in the wild, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Just make sure it's enqueued on the page that's actually firing the AJAX - can you see it when you view source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, but with the audio player.

First of all, you need enqueue MediaElement styles

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-mediaelement' );
```

Next you need to add *wp-mediaelement* as dependency of your app script or enqueue it.

```
wp_enqueue_script('wp-mediaelement');
```

or

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'app', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', array( 'jquery', 'wp-mediaelement' ));
```

As result you need something like that:

```
function my_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-mediaelement' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'app', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/app.js', array( 'jquery', 'wp-mediaelement' ));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
```